# Error: # of failed Map Tasks exceeded allowed limit. FailedCount: 1. on running Lucene search on Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, lucene, hadoop-streaming

I use each of the records in a big text file to perform a search on Lucene's index, then massage the results as i wanted and write to output.

I'm trying to use Hadoop by putting the big input text file and pre-created Lucene index onto Hadoop's file system. Then I changed my java program that does the file processing (read file records, search on Lucene, write output) to read records from Hadoop filesystem, and create Lucene index in memory. The command I kick off the Hadoop job is like below:

```
hadoop jar $HADOOP_HOME/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-1.0.3.jar  
          -libjars lucene-core-3.6.0.jar,hadoop-core-1.0.3.jar,concept.jar 
          -mapper "java concept.HadoopConceptRunner" 
          -input myBigInputFile 
          -output myOutput  
          -reducer NONE
```

Note that "concept.jar" contains concept.HadoopConceptRunner class and this is written by me.

My problem is that I can't get this Hadoop job to run correctly =.=". I got exception like below, and I'm unable to find anything else meaningful that can help me resolve this.

```
Error: # of failed Map Tasks exceeded allowed limit. FailedCount: 1.
```

and

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: BTW: What is the requirement for the java class that is used as a Mapper? Currently my concept.HadoopConceptRunner class doesn't extends or overwrite any hadoop class's method. Is this a possible problem? I am not sure this is a problem, since i used awk script with hadoop and it runs just fine...

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not be calling the java command but only give the fully qualified classname you want to be run as mapper. If the mapper called 'java concept.HadoopConceptRunner', I guess it would barf since the classpath is not defined thus the class would not be found ;)

So in short try again like this:

```
hadoop jar $HADOOP_HOME/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-1.0.3.jar  
       -libjars lucene-core-3.6.0.jar,hadoop-core-1.0.3.jar,concept.jar 
       -mapper "concept.HadoopConceptRunner" 
       -input myBigInputFile 
       -output myOutput  
       -reducer NONE
```

Also, I think the following is unlikely to work

```
-reducer NONE
```

you could try instead:

```
 -jobconf mapred.reduce.tasks=0
```